# Why are thioethers not better leaving groups than ethers?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reactivity, ethers

[image]

Why are thioethers ($\ce{RSR}$) not better leaving groups than ethers ($\ce{ROR}$)? I learnt that better bases are poorer leaving groups. Here, clearly   the poorer base is thioether, as the lone pair is on a larger atom.

Comment: Then you should unlearn it. Being a leaving group is only tangentially related to basicity, as you can see from this table.

Comment: What this chart doesn't cover (and would help you with your understanding) is what is meant by "leaving group ability?" Is it kinetics? Is it thermodynamics? You can't rationalize if you don't know what you're trying to rationalize.

Comment: @Zhe It's from Wikipedia....

Comment: @Mithoron It would be better if you explain why....

Comment: @blue Let's assume we are talking about thermodynamics. Then look at it by considering the reverse reaction. Is it easier to S-alkylate RSR or to O-alkylate ROR? Kinetics would be a little trickier to rationalise, as steric hindrance and other effects come into play.

Comment: Wikipedia is not a source. Go to the reference they are citing and figure out what it's actually measuring.